# Cannot see the Target Platforms node in the Project Manager in Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, target-platform

I want to build an existing 32-bit application for 64-bit Windows in Delphi XE3. But I cannot select the 64-Bit platform because I doesn't see the node 'Target Platforms' in the Project Manager. Do you have any idea what the reason could be?

This is what I should see:

[image]

I have the Professional Edition and have already built a lot of WIN64 applications.

Comment: I can see the Target Platforms node. You cannot. What's special about your project?

Comment: I have included a pic of what it's supposed to look like (taken in XE2)

Comment: What Delphi version was the existing 32-bit app created in?

Comment: Delphi XE. But I have migrated many XE/32 to XE3/64 projects without problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare your project's DPROJ file to your other projects that work OK with 64bit.  The failing project is likely missing a `<Platforms>` node that enables non-Win32 platforms, so the Project Manager would hide the Target Platforms node from view.

```xml
<Platforms>
    <Platform value="Win64">True</Platform>
    <Platform value="OSX32">False</Platform>
    <Platform value="Win32">True</Platform>
</Platforms>
```